# Как вынести дублирующую jQuery логику в функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, this

Сделал логику фокуса для инпут полей код рабочий, но согласитесь, плохо когда код дублируется:

```js
/* Для фокуса инпутов после ввода цифр в смс авторизации */
$('.input').on('keyup', function() {
  if (!this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 6);
    if ($(this).val().length === 6) {
      $(this).next('.confirm').focus();
    }
  } else {
    this.value = ''
  }
});

$('.field').on('keyup', function() {
  if (!this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 1);
    if ($(this).val().length === 1) {
      $(this).next().focus().select();
      $(this).next('.confirm').focus();
    }
  } else {
    this.value = ''
  }
});
```

```css
.field {width: 25px;}
hr {border-color: red;margin:32px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="auth-wait__fields">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">

  <button type="button" class="confirm">Подтвердить</button>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="auth-wait__fields">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="_">

  <button type="button" class="confirm">Подтвердить</button>
</div>
```

**Вынес её в функцию, но получаю ошибки:**

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')"

```js
// Для фокуса инпутов после ввода цифр в смс авторизации
function authFocus(sliceNum, oldMultiInput) {
  if (!this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, sliceNum);
    if ($(this).val().length === sliceNum) {
      if (oldMultiInput) {
        $(this).next().focus().select();
      }
      $(this).next('.auth-wait__send').focus();
    }
  } else {
    this.value = ''
  }
}

$('.input').on('keyup', function() {
  authFocus(6, false)
});


//Второй вариант вариант

$('.field').on('keyup', function() {
  authFocus(1, false)
});
```

```css
.field {width: 25px;}
hr {border-color: red;margin:32px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="auth-wait__fields">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">
  <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="_">

  <button type="button" class="confirm">Подтвердить</button>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="auth-wait__fields">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="_">

  <button type="button" class="confirm">Подтвердить</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызывает функцию, в которой нет элемента, this получить нельзя. Но Вы можете передать в эту функцию Ваш элемент и сразу с ним работать, примеры ниже:

```js
function Example_one(){
  /* this здесь не доступен */
  console.log(this.innerHtml); // ошибка
}

Example_one();

function Example_two (el){
  /* обращаюсь к объетку используя не this, а el */
  console.log(el.innerHtml);
}
Example_two(this); // Передаю свой объект используя ключевое слово this
```

*Примерно вот так это работает*